# SwiftUI LazyVStack overlapping images

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to display two columns of images in a LazyVStack embedded in a scroll view however the the second row of images partially overlaps the row above.  I'm not sure if this is an issue with the LazyVStack itself or an issue with the Photo.swift view.

The output looks like this
[image]
[image]

The two view files

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingCustomCamera = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State private var photos: [UIImage] = []
    
    func addImageToArray() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
        
        let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: inputImage.cgImage!)

        let options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options)!

        let faces = faceDetector.features(in: ciImage)

        if let face = faces.first as? CIFaceFeature {
            print("Found face at \(face.bounds)")

            print(face.faceAngle)
            print(face.hasSmile)
            print(face.leftEyeClosed)
            print(face.rightEyeClosed)
            
            if face.leftEyeClosed {
                print("Left Eye Closed \(face.leftEyePosition)")
            }

            if face.rightEyeClosed {
                print("Right Eye Closed \(face.rightEyePosition)")
            }

            if face.hasSmile {
                print("Person is smiling \(face.mouthPosition)")
            }
        }
        
        photos.append(inputImage)
    }
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                        AddPhoto(showCamera: $showingCustomCamera)
                        
                        ForEach(photos, id: \.self) { photo in
                            PassportPhoto(img: photo)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        //
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "printer.fill.and.paper.fill")
                        Text("Print")
                    })
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        //
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "externaldrive.fill.badge.icloud")
                        Text("Digital Upload")
                    })
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingCustomCamera, onDismiss: addImageToArray) {
                CustomCameraView(image: self.$inputImage)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Photos")
        }
    }
}
```

Photo.swift

```
struct Photo: View {
    var img: UIImage
    @State private var overlay: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Image(uiImage: img)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.width * 1.29, alignment: .top)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.overlay.toggle()
                        }
                    
                    if overlay {
                        Template()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

CustomCameraView.swift (as requested)

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
 
struct CustomCameraView: View {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @State var didTapCapture: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            CustomCameraRepresentable(image: self.$image, didTapCapture: $didTapCapture)
                .overlay(Template(),alignment: .center)
                .overlay(
                    CaptureButtonView().onTapGesture {
                        self.didTapCapture = true
                    }
                    , alignment: .bottom)
                .overlay(
                    Button(action: {
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "multiply")
                            .scaleEffect(2)
                            .padding(20)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }
                    })
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    , alignment: .topTrailing)
        }
    }
    
}


struct CustomCameraRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Binding var didTapCapture: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomCameraController {
        let controller = CustomCameraController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ cameraViewController: CustomCameraController, context: Context) {
        
        if(self.didTapCapture) {
            cameraViewController.didTapRecord()
        }
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        let parent: CustomCameraRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: CustomCameraRepresentable) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
            
            parent.didTapCapture = false
            
            if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
                parent.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}

class CustomCameraController: UIViewController {
    
    var image: UIImage?
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    //DELEGATE
    var delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?
    
    func didTapRecord() {
        
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: delegate!)
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    func setupCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }
    
    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                      mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                      position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
            
            switch device.position {
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.front:
                self.frontCamera = device
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.back:
                self.backCamera = device
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        
        self.currentCamera = self.backCamera
    }
    
    
    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    func setupPreviewLayer()
    {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.width * 1.29)
        
        self.cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = rect
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
        
    }
    func startRunningCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}


struct CaptureButtonView: View {
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "camera").font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(30)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color.red)
                    .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                    .opacity(Double(2 - animationAmount))
                    .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 1)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
        )
            .padding(.bottom)
            .onAppear
            {
                self.animationAmount = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code for CustomCameraView?

Comment: @aheze I've added it

Comment: It maybe that the "grid" is not getting the correct size of the "AddPhoto(...)".
Does the "AddPhoto(showCamera: $showingCustomCamera)" return a view with bounded size?
Try for example something similar to the PassportPhoto/Photo size:
"frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, maxHeight: geometry.size.width * 1.29)""

Comment: @workingdog It behaves the same way even if I remove the AddPhoto completely and just have it display an array of images.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t use `GeometryReader` from within the `ScrollView`, it will create all sort of mess for you. Instead define it at top level just under `VStack`, and pass the `proxy` down to ***Photo*** view to set Frame.

Check the code below-:

```
import SwiftUI


struct Test1: View {
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingCustomCamera = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State private var photos: [UIImage] = []
    
    func addImageToArray() {
        guard let inputImage = inputImage else { return }
        image = Image(uiImage: inputImage)
        
        let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: inputImage.cgImage!)
        
        let options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
        let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options)!
        
        let faces = faceDetector.features(in: ciImage)
        
        if let face = faces.first as? CIFaceFeature {
            print("Found face at \(face.bounds)")
            
            print(face.faceAngle)
            print(face.hasSmile)
            print(face.leftEyeClosed)
            print(face.rightEyeClosed)
            
            if face.leftEyeClosed {
                print("Left Eye Closed \(face.leftEyePosition)")
            }
            
            if face.rightEyeClosed {
                print("Right Eye Closed \(face.rightEyePosition)")
            }
            
            if face.hasSmile {
                print("Person is smiling \(face.mouthPosition)")
            }
        }
        
        photos.append(inputImage)
    }
    
    let columns =
        [GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20),
         GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 20)]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                            // AddPhoto(showCamera: $showingCustomCamera) // Uncomment in your case
                            
                            
                            ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { photo in
                                Photo(img: "ABC", proxy: geometry) // Pass photo as you were doing
                                
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        //
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "printer.fill.and.paper.fill")
                        Text("Print")
                    })
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        //
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "externaldrive.fill.badge.icloud")
                        Text("Digital Upload")
                    })
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingCustomCamera, onDismiss: addImageToArray) {
                // CustomCameraView(image: self.$inputImage)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Photos")
        }
    }
}

struct Photo: View {
    var img: String
    var proxy:GeometryProxy
    @State private var overlay: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        //  GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Image(img)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    // .frame(width: 170, height: 200)
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.4, height: proxy.size.width * 0.5, alignment: .top)
                    .clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.overlay.toggle()
                    }
                
                if overlay {
                    // Template()
                }
            }
        }
        //}
    }
}
```